# rospy publisher behaving different from rostopic pub

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu, rospy, ubuntu-precise, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to control my kinova mico manipulator arm through ROS python. I observed that when I use:

```
rostopic pub - r 10 /mico_arm_driver/in/cartesian_velocity geometry_msgs/TwistStamped "{header: {seq: 0, stamp: {secs: 0, nsecs: 0}, frame_id: ''}, 
twist: {linear: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.1}, angular: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}}}"
```

my manipulator moves smoothly. But, when I try to implement the same thing as python function, the movement is not smooth.

My function:

```
def worker(self):
    carvel_pub = rosy.Publisher('/mico_arm_driver/in/cartesian_velocity', geometry_msgs.msg.TwistStamped, queue_size=10)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10)
    while not rosy.is_shutdown():
        carvel_pub.publish(self._carvel_msg)
        rate.sleep()
```

I am using ROS Hydro with Ubuntu 12.04. I have two subscribers. I have already tried changing queue_size to None to see if it is a slowdown problem caused due to multiple subscribers.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217551/rospy-publisher-behaving-different-from-rostopic-pub/) by [ck28](https://answers.ros.org/users/23850/ck28/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your rospy publisher code isn't setting the `z` velocity at all, which means that it probably defaults to zero.

The fact that your robot moves at all suggests that there is another publisher which is sending a non-zero command.

Is it possible that you have two publishers that are sending conflicting commands?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ck28](https://answers.ros.org/users/23850/ck28/) on 2015-09-12**:
I have another function that sets self._carvel_msg which is a global variable. Also, I have checked the value received at subscriber and it is as desired.

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2015-09-13**:
Did you checked the publishing frequence in both cases with `rostopic hz /name_of_topic`?